# Edit /etc/resolv.conf using PHP

Tags: php, linux, dns

I want to add new DNS on my server. I'm able to edit the file /etc/resolv.conf using vi editor.

But, when I try using PHP.. the file is not opening.

What could be the issue?

Please suggest / provide me with a solution to fix this.

Comment: Does apache webservices user have access? I doubt it!

Comment: you can use nano, vim , gedit

Comment: it might be because of permissions, check permissions of the /etc/resolv.conf, before running your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your PHP is running on a different user then when you login to the server yourself. You will have read/write access to the file and PHP doesnt.

Now increasing the rights of the PHP users could cause a security issue, so I would advise against it. But you could grant the user access to that specific file only if realy needed. Check [Granting Access Permission to a file to a specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355625/granting-access-permission-to-a-file-to-a-specific-user) on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks.. I used chown to grant the permissions and it worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need root access to modify /etc/hosts .

- You can `chmod 666` /etc/hosts, but this would be a security issue.
- But so is running PHP under root,
- and so is `chown`ing the /etc/hosts.

So there you have 3 (insecure) solutions. With the last one being least evil.

You might also be facing a struggle with PHP accessing files if PHP is restricted to files inside a certain directory. ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir )